# Why does the program only give an output if defined in main (and how can I change this)?

Tags: c, function, output, program-entry-point

I tried to run this

```
int array( void )
{
    char text[12] = {  112, 114, 111, 103, 112, 0 };
    int i;
    for(i = 0; text[i]; i = i +1)
        printf("%c", text[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    int array(void);
    return 0;
}
```

and the program runs but I am getting no result. Now when I use the main function to define the program:

```
int main( void )
{
    char text[12] = {  112, 114, 111, 112, 0 };
    int i;
    for(i = 0; text[i]; i = i +1)
        printf("%c", text[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the result `progr`(as wanted). I already searched but the only related questions I find are about using `main` as a function name and wrong outputs. Maybe I am searching the wrong way but I would be pleased if someone could answer this.

Comment: Try removing the `int` from `int array(void);`.

Comment: `int array(void);` is just a prototype - it doesn't *call* the function. To call, do: `array()`.

Comment: original typo to say the least.

Comment: Presumably you know you could make your code more readable by using `char text[12] = {  'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'p', 0 };` (or, of course, `char text[12] = "progp";`).

Comment: Please do not use magic numbers. The array should be `char text[12] = { 'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'p', 0 );` but better as `char text[12] = "progp";` (@SteveSummit used the other snippet (until edited)).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. Now it works

Comment: I know now that using magic numbers is no good but as i am trying to learn c in the first place i just wanted to try it out. It was only an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direct problem is that you did not **call the function** `array`, you 
`declare` it inside the body of `main`. **The declaration itself does not execute the code.**

A function **declaration** tells the compiler about a function's name, return type, and parameters.

A function **definition** provides the actual body of the function.

**Defining a Function**

The general form of a function definition in C programming language is as follows

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   body of the function
}
```

In your case you have two function definitions:

```
// 1.
int array( void )
{
    char text[12] = {  112, 114, 111, 103, 112, 0 };
    int i;
    for(i = 0; text[i]; i = i +1)
        printf("%c", text[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

// 2.
int main(void)
{
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

**Function Declarations**

A function declaration tells the compiler about a function name and how to call the function. The actual body of the function can be defined separately.

```
int array(void); // function declaration, no parameters, returns int value
```

**Calling a Function**

**To call a function, you simply need to pass the required parameters along with the function name, and if the function returns a value, then you can store the returned value.**

In your case call it like this:

```
 array();
```

since there are no parameters to pass.

To sum up:

```
int array(void);   // function declaration, no parameters, returns int value 

int array(void)    // definition of the function `array`
{   
    // function body
    char text[12] = {  112, 114, 111, 103, 112, 0 };
    // ...
    return 0;
}   

int main(void)    // definition of the function `main`, 
{
  array();        // function call, calling function `array` with no parameters
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much for that extensive information

Answer (score 3):

Since the function returns `int`, You should've assigned its return value to `int` too. **OR**
You can just call it normally with only its name because it always returns a `0` constant.

```
int i = array(); // i = 0
// or
array();
```

It's just **printing** and its value is always `0`.
Then I suggest making it `void` instead because You'll need to call it by name only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void array()
{
    char text[12] = {  112, 114, 111, 103, 112, 0 };
    for(int i = 0; text[i]; i++)
        printf("%c", text[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    array();
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** that You can't assign the type `void` to anything.

Comment: Well, I know, but his function has nothing to do with the return value anyway so it's just printing, I didn't say to worry about the return value but to improve his code, `i = i +1` >> `i++`, also no need to type `void` everywhere since compilers already smart enough to optimize this.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments on the question, instead of this...

```
int main(void)
{
  int array(void);
  return 0;
}
```

You should instead write

```
int main(void)
{
  array(void);
  return 0;
}
```

This is because when saying `int something();` you are declaring a prototype of a function called `something` that takes in no parameters and returns an int. Instead, you need to invoke that function simply by typing `something();`.

Comment: I'm sure that you meant he's **declaring**, while **defining** means the actual body of the function between the scopes.

Answer (score 2):

`int array(void);` inside of `main` is only a declaration.  You are telling to the compiler that you have a function elsewhere that is called `array` that it takes no parameters, and returns nothing.  But in no case the `array` function is being called on main.  To call it just change the declaration to an statement like:

```
int main()
{
     int array(void); // you tell compiler that you have a function array.
     array();  // you are executing the code of array();
     return 0;
}
```